# Nginx 444 error eqivalent in Apache?

Tags: nginx, http, apache2

Is there any way to produce same Nginx 444 error in apache.

Nginx

> 444--> Connection Closed Without Response.

I like this error since if anyone tries to CURL he gets an empty response, but not so in Apache.

Comment: Most likely with custom error responses: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html if I am not mistaken.

Comment: but not defined "how to create connection closed error"

Comment: No, in that case you'd use: `ErrorDocument 444 "Connection Closed Without Response"`

Comment: You are not getting my point sir. For example here is the IP with NGINX 444 error. http://95.211.150.66/. But with your solution users will read a text which i don't want to show.

Comment: As far as I know, Apache doesn't have the equal functionality to the nginx 444 "error code". It is not an HTTP actual error code but an immediate shutdown of TCP connection.

Comment: the are no real drawbacks at leaving nginx in front of apache even in a local setup (except in the case of a embedded and resource limited setup). Isn't this an option in your case?

Answer (score 2):

444 is not returned to the client, it is only written into nginx logs signalling that a connection was closed with no response. This same firewall-like behavior can be achieved in apache using modsecurity and DROP actions.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps...

I use Apache as a reverse proxy for a web app on port 3000, and I wanted to simply drop certain bogus requests with extreme prejudice — e.g., it's not WordPress, so I don't even want to dignify `/wp-admin` probes with a response!

Anyway, I installed `mod_security` as suggested, and added the following `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/10-empty-response.conf` entry; now my app can return a "444" status, and the proxy will drop the connection:

```
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS 444 "id:'444444',phase:3,log,drop"
```

Answer (score -2):

Custom, non-standard HTTP response codes such as 444 do not seem to be supported by Apache.
I could not find an exhaustive list of allowed codes in Apache's documentation for the [ErrorDocument directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument), however testing with something like

```
    <Location /444>
        ErrorDocument 444 "Something"
    </Location>
```

Doesn't even allow Apache to load, whereas changing the `444` above to `404` allows Apache to load without any errors or problems.